# Consequences of using statements in conditions of if statement PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

This might be an obvious question, but I haven't found the answer anywhere.

So if I check if a function is working or not, I put it in an if() condition, like this:

`if(!fopen($filename, "w")) print "file not found";`

But does it open the file? And does it erase it? (the mode "w" would cause that.)

Thanks!

Comment: the `w` mode opens the file for writting, it doesn't erase it. However, if you ask if the function is really called - it is. But if it return "file not found", it does not return true

Comment: @RoyalBg You can open yet non-existent files this way, so the error message will be wrong.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel sure, that's why I said the function is returning false by some reason, not that really the file is not found :) The error message should be changed, or to check for not found use `file_exists()`

Comment: please don't go into unnecessary details. I made up a code, sorry for it being incorrect. i just wanted to know if the function in the condition has its regular consequences or not.

Comment: You could also use short-circuit evaluation: `fopen($filename, 'w') || echo "Something went wrong.";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a function in an `if` statement will be executed as is.

Comment: To expand on Marc's answer it means that if `(fopen($filename, "w"))` evaluates to `TRUE` then the `fopen` has been successfully executed.

Comment: @Sébastien To be more precise: `(!fopen($filename, "w"))` will evaluate to `FALSE` if `fopen` executes successfully.

Comment: Sorry! You're right, I corrected my comment. Damn copy/paste! Thank You :)